# Advanced Search Tool

Tags: search, text

I am looking for a tool that is capable of displaying multiple text side by side along with an another file that contains the search string. Once I click every line in the search string file, tool will take the default pointer of the search result in each of the input files.

I would appreciate if you could share the reference of such tool.

For your information, I have checked the AstroGrep application; but this is not that much advanced to level of efficiency that I want.

Comment: As AstroGrep seems to be a Windows utility your question is about a Windows based tool?

Answer (score 1):

[VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) does a pretty good job displaying search results: (watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uc4I4ByUe0A for an overview)

By default it will open the results in a new tab but you can drag the tab to display the split window view.